# MVC Partial view not going into HttpPost

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on a website in MVC, At the bottom of my footer I have a textbox with a button to signup for newsletter. I created a partial view for this textbox & button. I'm trying to achieve when clicking on the submit button to instantly go to the HttpPost and skip the HttpGet.

**NewsletterController:**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewsletterEmail(string email)
    {
        // Logic
    }
```

**NewsletterModel:**

```
    [Key]
    public int EmailID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

**_Layout.cshml:**

```
<div class="subs-social-options">
                    <div class="row custom-row-footer">
                        <div class="col-md-6 custom-col-options">
                                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Newslett/AddNewsletterEmail.cshtml");
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="right-side">
                                <div class="widget widget-footer social-icons">
                                    <h2>Get Social with Us</h2>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.twitter.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://www.flickr.com/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-flickr"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

**AddNewsletterEmail.cshtml (partial view):**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNewsletterEmail", "NewsletterController", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "email", HttpMethod = "Post"}))
{
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="widget widget-footer news-letter-signup">
            <form class="subs-form">
                <div class="email-field">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { placeholder = "Enter you email address" })
                    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i></button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I have been looking for serveral hours for a solution and nothing worked yet, so any help is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Regards, Vexena

Comment: The code you have shown will work fine. What is the problem your having?

Comment: Right now, when clicking on the submit button from the partial view it seems to go to the HttpGet first which is not what I want, I would to place the string from textbox input into the database with the HttpPost so the view remains tesame

Comment: The code you have shown will go to the POST method. If its not, it suggests you may have nested forms in your view (which is invalid)

Comment: I don't think I have any nested forms in my _layout.cshtml, atleast not any that i'm aware off. I have uploaded the full code from this page on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/cjaYxK1c

Comment: You do have nested forms. Look at the very first line of code in the pastebin

Comment: I see, if I am correct I can have as many forms as I want just not nest them? I will attempt to remove the nesting and see if I will get this working, Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Just remove the `BeginForm()` and its braces from the layout and it will work fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109286/discussion-between-vexena-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: After removing the nesting from the layout it did not seem to work, I attempted to create a new  MVC project just to reproduce it with less code but that did not return me the post either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNewsletterEmail", "Newsletter", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "email", HttpMethod = "Post"}))
```

All I had to do was change **NewsletterController to Newsletter** in order to fix it (I think Ajax.Beginform already appends Controller to the stated overload?) Correct me i'f i'm wrong.

Special thanks to [Nataraj](http://forums.asp.net/members/Nataraj%20Gandhi%20Arunachalam.aspx) from asp.net forum!

Comment: `Ajax.Beginform()` does not append "Controller". The convention in MVC is to access a controller named `XYZController`, you use `"XYZ"`. This applies throughout MVC, for example when using `Html.BeginForm()`, `Url.Action()`, `Html.Action()` and all methods that accept a controller name.